# In space, if 2 free electrons are brought together and then released from external forces, do they eventually reach half $c$?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, energy, coulombs-law

I did a number of simulations of particles in motion based on Coulomb potential and the like. One constant consequence of establishing a repulsion between particles of same sign even at far distance, is that those particles not only avoid each other by taking opposite directions, but accelerate over time because their velocities accumulate the acceleration "transmitted" by the Coulomb field.

I did not limit the speed of propagation of the Coulomb force, so this is unphysical. However, even if I did, I suppose particles would cease to transmit an acceleration to the others only if their distance increases faster than the speed of light. That would mean e.g. 2 particles moving apart at half $c$ (speed relative to the initial contact point).

The problem I have with this hypothesis, is that I cannot see how such energetic particles could emerge from a simple initial containment and still respect energy conservation. Any light?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101531/discussion-on-question-by-exocytosis-in-space-if-2-free-electrons-are-brought-t).

Comment: They can still be viewed - and if they are answers, they don't belong in the comments anyway. So if there are actual answers in there worth keeping, they should be posted as actual answers.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a simple conservation of energy problem. "Transmitting" acceleration doesn't make sense; there's always a force, but it decreases, and there's no reason to think that leads to infinite acceleration.

Potential energy of the two electrons: $E = 2ke^2/r$ where $k$ is the Coulomb constant, and the kinetic energy at the end is $2 (\gamma-1) mc^2$. With $v = 0.5c$, $\gamma \sim 1.15$. Solving gives $r = 1.8 \times 10^{-14}$ meters. Any smaller than this value and the two electrons will reach $0.5c$, any further and they won't.

Comment: I disagree. Coulomb interaction is not instantaneous. There IS a delay of propagation of the force. Secondly, I never proposed an infinite acceleration but suggested it was limited by propagation delay (not to mention C as an upper limit).

Comment: I should add that having an equation for the end result does not explain the kinetics, and this is probably why you don't realize the acceleration of the electrons is absolutely not discontinuous.

Comment: @Exocytosis ?? “the acceleration of the electrons is absolutely not discontinuous”??

Comment: Of course it is not discontinuous, plank scale apart. If you put two electrons close to each other they will gain speed in a continuous fashion.